# How to crack an Excel workbook that looks up values?

Tags: excel

Alright I know this isn't 100% related to programming (the Excel book in question doesn't use VBA at all) but I'm hoping someone can help me out with this or point me in the right direction.

My boss got a spreadsheet from a vendor that has a combobox/dropdown list with various part numbers; when you select one it populates the rest of the form with a lookup containing additional items.  I've been tasked with "cracking" this and finding the list that they're using to populate so we can make use of it.

The thing is... there's no VBA code, no macros, no data connections, and only one Worksheet displayed in Excel while the lookup code references a `Sheet1`.  I've tried to display hidden worksheets and it says there are none... so where on earth could this list be kept?  My boss is getting impatient and is asking me if I've broken it yet.  It's not a big deal if it can't be done, I just have no clue where to continue looking for it and I don't know what to tell my boss when he asks me if I'm done.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what version of excel? Usually the drop downs have a range somewhere that they reference, but what version of excel are you using and what version is the original document?

Comment: I'm using 2007, I don't know what version the original is, possibly 2003

Comment: Click the dropdown to get it selected (right click seems to work better, you'll have the "dots" on the control), then hit the "Properties" icon in the Developer toolbar, go to the Control Tab, check the input range...that may start you down the path

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a DropDown list control (clicking Properties gives me properties for the whole sheet, as though there are no controls on it), but when I click on the cell I get a little "button" that when I click it, gives me a dropdown list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is a Data Validation list which references a constant list of values or a range on a "Very Hidden" sheet. In Excel 2007, select one of the cells with the drop-down, click on the "Data" tab in the Ribbon, click on "Data Validation" in the Ribbon and see what you have. In Excel 2003 it is the Data -> Validation... command.

Another possibility if you know the name of the worksheet is "Sheet1" is to add a new worksheet, enter "=Sheet1!A1" into cell A1 of the new worksheet, and copy this cell down and to the right for as large of an area as you need to see the data you are interested in.

If you can post a URL to download the workbook (assuming it is not a trade secret) you would be more likely to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Okay that helped - It gave me a source list but I still can't access the sheet.  It looks to be encrypted or something to prevent modification (makes sense to me) and reverse engineering

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to hide a worksheet using VBA so that it can't be unhidden from the UI.

Try the method for un-hiding all hidden workhseets outlined here:

http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/12/14/excel_vba_unhide_all_worksheets/

Answer (score 0):

Could it be some data stored on the same sheet.
Possibly in columns which are either hidden, or which are far off the actual page?

Comment: I checked for that already... the call to VLOOKUP references a range of columns in a different sheet.

Comment: Your sheet isn't called Sheet1 is it? (Just checking.)

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of what you're seeing? Minus all the sensitive bits? That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just data from the worksheet only?

Column header dropdown lists acts as filters, they show distinct values of a column.
This is a feature of Excel.

Comment: It's not the header, it's a dropdown in each column of that row.

Comment: However when I go to "design mode" it doesn't show up as being a combobox control.  I'm not that familiar with Excel so I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you confirming these are not auto filters?

Comment: In Excel 2007, if you mark a column and choose Filter->Filter by selected cell's value, this will create a sort of dropdown that can be used to filter the column by values.
You see any gaps in the row numbers? If you do, this is definitely it, since then numbers that does not appear, is filtered out

Answer (score 0):

The items could be cached from a currently unavailable resource.  Try saving it out to xml and searching for a known string.

Comment: That didn't work - I got a message stating the workbook contains no XML mappings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the cell that display a drop down list when selected
2. From the menubar select data>validation
3. In the dialog box copy the content of the source text box
4. Now paste the content on any empty cell on your worksheet
5. Select a drag it down to see the values populating the list

Chris
------
Convert your Excel spreadsheet into an online calculator.
http://www.spreadsheetconverter.com

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have broken this by now, but just in case you havent.  This is certainly a case of data validation using a named range which is house on another sheet that was designated "very Hidden" from the vba console.  You will need to open up the VBA project of this worksheet and designated the "very Hidden" sheet to just Hidden and then you will be able to unhide it, or the other setting at which point it will be viewable.